# appending string to a list from an other list

Tags: python

well, I have 2 lists (names and bilananu2017) names contains the names of companies and bilananu2017 contain a pdf of each company there is some missing links the problem is that names length is 80 and bilananu2017 length is 75 i want both lists to be the same length so I can make a data frame. I have this idea of adding a string "null" in bilananu2017 for each missing link
basically ill compare each company name with all the link if there a link that contains the campany name then append the link in a new list if not append("null") so at the end ill have a new list with the length of names where there is null for each missing link
i tried this code

```
for n in names:
    t=False
    for b in bilananu2017:
        if n in b:
            bilananu2017_2.append(b)
            t=True
    if t==False:
        bilananu2017_2.append("Null")
```

it does the work but for somehow  bilananu2017 length is now 89 ??? its supposed to be 80
so i tried this code:

```
for n in names:
    t=False
    if any(n in bil for bil in bilananu2017):
        bilananu2017_2.append(bil)
        t=True
    if t==False:
        bilananu2017_2.append("Null")
```

now I got an error that says bil is not defined well that's obvious but how can I fix it ?

that's what i have in names

```
['ab', 'adwya', 'aetec', 'al', 'alkim', 'ams', 'artes', 'assad', 'ast', 'atb', 'atl', 'tjari', 'tjl', 'maghrebia', 'bl', 'bh', 'ml', 'biat', 'bna', 'bt', 'bte', 'salim', 'cc', 'cell', 'creal', 'cil', 'scb', 'city', 'dh', 'lstr', 'nakl', 'sokna', 'ecycl', 'gif', 'hl', 'icf', 'lndor', 'mag', 'mip', 'mnp', 'mpbs', 'nbl', 'oth', 'office', 'pltu', 'pgh', 'sah', 'sam', 'smd', 'servi', 'sfbt', 'siame', 'simpa', 'sipha', 'sits', 'somoc', 'sopat', 'sotem', 'sotet', 'stpap', 'stpil', 'mgr', 'sotuv', 'spdit', 'star', 'stb', 'steq', 'stip', 'tgh', 'tlnet', 'tpr', 'tinv', 'tre', 'tair', 'tls', 'uadh', 'ubci', 'uib', 'unimed', 'wifack']
```

in bilananu2017 its 75 links so ill put 4 so you can have an idea:

```
http://www.bvmt.com.tn/sites/default/files/societes/ab/etats-financiers/ab-etats-financiers-annuels-31-12-2017.pdf',
 'http://www.bvmt.com.tn/sites/default/files/societes/adwya/etats-financiers/adwya-etats-financiers-annuels-individuels-31-12-2017.pdf',
 'http://www.bvmt.com.tn/sites/default/files/societes/aetec/etats-financiers/aetec-etats-financiers-annuels-31-12-2017.pdf', 
'http://www.bvmt.com.tn/sites/default/files/societes/alkim/etats-financiers/alkim-etats-financiers-annuels-individuels-31-12-2017.
```

for example:
the first name in names is "ab" if we try to look in the link for that name we will find that the first link contains "ab"

```
http://www.bvmt.com.tn/sites/default/files/societes/ab/etats-financiers/ab-etats-financiers-annuels-31-12-2017.pdf
```

here /societes/ab

Comment: Please try to write in complete, clear sentences. I can't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: How are you associating the company names with the links? Because in your code, you're trying to match the company name with the link string which are obviously two different strings.

Comment: i updated  it re read it please now its more clear and i made an example at the end

Comment: @LouayGOURRIDA I have modified the code and used regex try it out if it works fine

Comment: @Cute Panda the first code somehow return 79 instead of 80 but now it works perfectly thank you so much

Comment: @LouayGOURRIDA Most Welcome, the reason is Regex is more accurate and reliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will work fine:

```
import re

names=['ab','bbb','ccc','adwya'] #Dummy Data
bilananu2017=['http://www.bvmt.com.tn/sites/default/files/societes/ab/etats-financiers/ab-etats-financiers-annuels-31-12-2017.pdf', 'http://www.bvmt.com.tn/sites/default/files/societes/adwya/etats-financiers/adwya-etats-financiers-annuels-individuels-31-12-2017.pdf']
pattern = re.compile("http:\/\/www\.bvmt\.com\.tn\/sites\/default\/files\/societes\/(.*?)\/")
toBeAdded = []
for i in range(len(names)):
    status=False
    for bil in bilananu2017:
        x=re.search(pattern, bil)
        if x:
            if names[i] == x.group(1):
                status = True
                break
    if(status==False):
        toBeAdded.append(i)

for i in toBeAdded:
    bilananu2017.insert(i,"Null")

print(bilananu2017)
```

**Output**

```
['http://www.bvmt.com.tn/sites/default/files/societes/ab/etats-financiers/ab-etats-financiers-annuels-31-12-2017.pdf', 'Null', 'Null', 'http://www.bvmt.com.tn/sites/default/files/societes/adwya/etats-financiers/adwya-etats-financiers-annuels-individuels-31-12-2017.pdf']
```